# Android Linkify phone number in textview not working for nexus 7

Tags: android, textview

I'm having trouble creating a phone number link on Nexus 7 version 4.4.4. So far this works seamlessly on all 3 of my Samsung devices on 4.2, 4.1 and 5.0

Here is my code

```
Linkify.addLinks(orderCompleteTextView, Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES | Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
orderCompleteHereTextView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
```

Is there any way around this

Answer (score 2):

Nexus 7 tab **doesn't** support **Calling**. So finally not possible on Nexus 7 Tab.

Comment: I get links on my Samsung Galaxy 10.1 and it doesn't support calling but I can save contacts.

Comment: @Amanni, Can you please check https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6388, Add Need that pound (#) sign and try again

Comment: Changed from 01-488 9950  to  01-488 9950# and still not working

Comment: This is also true if your device doesn't have a SIM card in.